# OCI doesn't show changes to records made from another (non-OCI) session

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I'm using `OCI` for working with an Oracle database.  This works perfectly when inserting, selecting, deleting, etc.

But when I insert some data to the same database and table via the SQL command line `OCI` doesn't show those changes.

Why can I not see the inserted data via `OCI`?

Comment: I'm glad that I could help and your problem is resolved.  Please read ['What should I do when someone answers my question?'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to understand more about how SO works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `commit` the changes in your command line session before any other session will see them.

By default the `OCI8` extension in PHP [auto-commits at the end of execution](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php#refsect1-function.oci-execute-parameters), if successful.  This is unusual for Oracle, where the user must always explicitly `commit` or `rollback` any changes.